# Scraping multiple pages beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrap multiple pages for links to documents. so i set up a string to vary the page number (in the example below from page 1 to page 6) - i loop the string into the url - but when I parse for the links with beautiful soup - i only get the high range - ie i overwite all of the previous pages.

the code...

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
pages = [str(i) for i in range(1,6)]
for page in pages:
    response = get('http://www.sedar.com/FindCompanyDocuments.do?lang=EN&page_no=' + page + '&company_search=All+%28or+type+a+name%29&document_selection=24&industry_group=A&FromDate=01&FromMonth=01&FromYear=2017&ToDate=06&ToMonth=12&ToYear=2017&Variable=DocType')
page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

for link in page_html.find_all('a'):
   print(link.get('title'))
```

with 6 pages i was expecting around 600 links - but as I say, I seem to be only get the last part of the range. (BTW - the output link is fine and correct i will prefix the http address at a later stage. As i newbie, im guessing there is a simple soltuion i havent seen (not for want of finding :))

```
None
&docClass=24&issuerNo=00040114&issuerType=03&projectNo=02637890&docId=4133021
None
&docClass=24&issuerNo=00005620&issuerType=03&projectNo=02700766&docId=4219364
None
&docClass=24&issuerNo=00005620&issuerType=03&projectNo=02700766&docId=4219365
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should indent the last 3 lines, so they're part of the iteration. It was only processing the last part after all the iterations were complete.

```
for page in pages:
    response = get('http://www.sedar.com/FindCompanyDocuments.do?lang=EN&page_no=' + page + '&company_search=All+%28or+type+a+name%29&document_selection=24&industry_group=A&FromDate=01&FromMonth=01&FromYear=2017&ToDate=06&ToMonth=12&ToYear=2017&Variable=DocType')
    page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    for link in page_html.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('title'))
```

Comment: thanks so much. Simple - (i did say i was new at this!!)